# Unable to deploy a keypair via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, gitlab-ci-runner, key-pair

When going to deploy my Terraform code, I am getting the following errors:

[image: Error Message]

[image]

I'm unsure what I need to do to get this working? My Terraform code looks fine, it looks more like a permission issue.

This pipeline is ran via a GitLab Runner.

Comment: It's a public runner or your own runner? What kinds of runners you are using ( on VM, docker, k8s)?

Comment: This is a private runner that is using provided by an external party.

Comment: Does that mean the private runner on account B (managed by an external party) and you want to create a key pair in account A? How can you provide AWS access permission to that runner (access keys stored in environment variables or assume role or ...)? I think It depends on how they created runners (VM, docker, k8s). Btw, you are using their service, why not ask your external party?

Answer (score 0):

It is written in your error message: you are not authorized to perform this action.

your runner needs a role, that has policy which allows him to do it.

Comment: This is my Policy attached to my GitLab Runner: